# How to use multiple optional parameters in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, parameters

I am trying to do a simple UDF in VBA: I want to get the quarter of a date.

I can do a basic version easily that works (I am French, so quarters are noted as *trimestres* and abbreviated by a T) :

```
Public Function Trimestre(MaDate As Date) As String

Trimestre = Year(MaDate) & "-" & "T" & (((Month(MaDate) - 1) \ 3) + 1)

End Function
```

Then I would like to add two possibilities of customization :

- Enable the user to choose the separator, i.e. the `-`
- Enable the user to choose the English version, i.e. replace the `T` by a `Q`

I can do one variation at a time :

```
Public Function Trimestre(MaDate As Date, Optional Langue As String = "FR") As String

If Langue = "FR" Then
Trimestre = Year(MaDate) & "-" & "T" & (((Month(MaDate) - 1) \ 3) + 1)
End If     
If Langue = "EN" Then
Trimestre = Year(MaDate) & "-" & "Q" & (((Month(MaDate) - 1) \ 3) + 1)
End If  

End Function
```

Or

```
Public Function Trimestre(MaDate As Date, Optional Sep As String = "-") As String

Trimestre = Year(MaDate) & Sep & "T" & (((Month(MaDate) - 1) \ 3) + 1)

End Function
```

But then when I try to combine the two, I get errors.

For instance,

```
Public Function Trimestre(MaDate As Date, Optional ByVal Sep As String = "-", Optional Langue As String = "FR") As String

If Langue = "FR" Then
Trimestre = Year(MaDate) & Sep & "T" & (((Month(MaDate) - 1) \ 3) + 1)
End If
If Lanque = "EN" Then
Trimestre = Year(MaDate) & Sep & "Q" & (((Month(MaDate) - 1) \ 3) + 1)
End If

End Function
```

Used with `=Trimestre(C14;Langue="EN")` gives a `#Value` error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I edited my question and added an example

Comment: Have a look here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/optional-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the error because you are also entering the argument name `Langue` with the formula. The correct formula on your sheet should be `=Trimestre(C4,,"EN")`. Change the comma to semi-colon in case you get error with your Excel setting.

[image]

Comment: So the order in which I place my optional parameters matter : I can specify only two parameters, but it will necessary assume it is in the order in which I have put them in the function, and I have no way to tell only the third parameter if I want the second one to remain on a default value ?

Comment: In VBA, you can specify `Langue:=` parameter and it will be accepted. On the worksheet, you should follow the way the parameters are declared.